# How to use whole rotation of log potentiometer?

Tags: audio, potentiometer

I want to use a Log Potentiometer to adjust the loudness of a speaker. Therefore I connected the [Stereo logarithmic pot with 10 kOhm](http://www.distrelec.ch/de/Kohle-Potentiometer-2x-log-10-kOhm-%C2%B1-20-%25-Piher-PC16DH07CP04-103B2020--TA/p/16428452) resistance to a [Sonos CONNECT:AMP](http://www.sonos.com/shop/products/connectamp) with an output of max. 110W (8 Ohm). Generally this works but the loudness is only adjusted in the last say 10% of the rotation on the right side.

How can this be fixed? Probably the 10 kOhm resistance of the pot is the problem. I searched for stereo pots with smaller resistances but they seem to be very rare. Is it possible to fix it with the used pot?

The Poti is connected like this:

[image: Schematic]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Could you possibly provide a circuit diagram/ schematic to make it more clear what the problem is?

Comment: You're not supposed to connect the pot between the amp and the  speaker.

Comment: Where to put the poti when not between the amp and the speaker? In Sonos the source and amp is combined.

Comment: Again, you're not supposed to connect the pot between the amp and the speaker.  If you **must** attenuate the output of the amp for some reason, you should use an L-pad between the amp and the speaker.  Something like this, perhaps: http://www.parts-express.com/speaker-l-pad-attenuator-100w-mono-1-shaft-8-ohm--260-265

Comment: "Where to put the pot when not between the amp and the speaker?" RTFM.

Comment: @EMFields Thanks for the Advice to use an L-pad.
Responding with a RTFM is not helpfull if there are only two outputs coming from Sonos amp an the input is processed inside the amp. I see no other place to put the poti.

Comment: That's why you should RTFM. Sonos' sales literature states that it's possible to control the units from any wireless device, so a look into the manual may provide a clue on how to adjust the volume without having to use a wasteful pad. And, by the way, the accepted contraction for "potentiometer" isn't "poti", it's "pot".

Comment: @EMFields Me likes RTFM - I figured what it was but checked online!!

Comment: @Andyaka - You are so young, and so well (badly?) treated ;-) In the '80's, when I taught undergraduates, we wore "RTFM" badges. We simply tapped them when it became obvious a student was asking a question that was well-answered in the manual. After a few weeks, one could listen, look quizzically, and they 'got it', and pointed at the badges themselves. I think we did them a very great service. They figured out how to search on-line manuals, the quality of questions improved significantly, and they seemed to progress faster. I assume you know fubar and snafu?

Comment: @gbulmer I've led a very sheltered life me heartie

Answer (score 4):

Putting a pot inline with the speakers means the pot is trying to dissipate all of the power that's no longer going to the speaker, most pots are NOT made for this - a 110W pot would weigh several kilos and give off as much heat as, well, a 110W light bulb. It's like trying to regulate your car's speed by putting a brick on the accelerator and then just riding the brakes all the time to slow you down - dumb, pointless, and something's going to catch fire pretty soon.

The way 99.9% of volume controls work is by attenuating the small low-power **input signal** to the amplifier or pre-amp inside the unit.

Also, the unit you linked to clearly has volume buttons on the front, as well as claimed WiFi control, so perhaps you haven't explained fully what your specific problem is?

If you want to add a "hardware" volume knob to the thing, you're probably going to have to crack it open and do some surgery. If that's beyond you then FFS leave it alone and find another way to solve the problem. Old 70's / 80's hifi stereo amps are cheap and plentiful and more interesting, probably sound better too. See what you can rescue from the small ads for a few bucks. Bonus if it comes with some big-ass speakers with proper woofers & tweeters. Buy all of it based on heavier = better, you won't be far off.